# Best Keyboard with a built-in pointing device for a media center Mac?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, media-center, input-device

I've got a Mac Mini as my home entertainment machine, and I'm currently using a regular wireless keyboard and mouse combo. I don't really have a great mousing surface, so I'd like to use something like a trackpad or trackball.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

The keyboard doesn't have to be Mac specific. I have no problems using OS X's key remapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Logitech diNovoEdge](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/4429&&cl=us,en)

Comment: I like them, but they just feel so pricey...

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Logitech Bluetooth Mediaboard Pro](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/gaming/playstation_3/devices/3616&cl=US,EN) with my PS3/Linux and I believe it works well with a Mac Mini (caveated with the keyboard mapping).  Lightweight, trackpad works well and is integrated, and the fact that it's bluetooth is nice compared with IR.

Comment: looks interesting. Did anyone got it working fine with mac mini?

Comment: looks like it's got mixed feelings from mac users: http://www.123macmini.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=109976

Answer (score 1):

I use this one, and have found it to be excellent and 100% reliable. It has also withstood the kids for a year now...

http://www.ebuyer.com/product/104608

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone [Air Mouse Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=289616509&mt=8) might be a solution.

Comment: I do have AirMouse, but it only feels like a temporary, quick-fix, solution, i.e. if I don't feel like grabbing the keyboard and mouse because it'll only take me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with a mac, but I've used [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Accuratus-Saturn-Wireless-Keyboard-Trackball/dp/B000IZSP5E) one with my PC and found the trackball very accurate and quick to move around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I *also* like my diNovo Edge, but as it gets older, the battery has stopped keeping a charge.  I also might recommend the much more svelte..  [Logitech diNovo Mini].  It's surprisingly fast for text entry, has a pointer pad, and is, spiritually, much closer brethren to the old "remote" than the "edge".[1](http://amzn.to/RV453D)…

[image]