# Controller Device for Media Center Computer

Tags: keyboard, product-rec, htpc, media-center

I am in the process of deciding on what to choose a a controller for a Media Center Computer.

I have seen the question *[Best Keyboard with a built-in pointing device for a media center Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/903/best-keyboard-with-a-built-in-pointing-device-for-a-media-center-mac)* but it doesn't have many answers, perhaps because of the Mac in the title.

I am looking for something like a keyboard with a tracking device, but perhaps there are other alternatives. What would be your recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a [Logitech diNovo mini](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/3848&cl=US,EN) controller.  I'm reasonably happy with it but the keys feel a little fragile and I'm not sure how they will last.

Answer (score 1):

[Logitech diNovoEdge](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/192&cl=us,en) looks nice but it is quite expansive, There is also a [Mac edition](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/4429&cl=us,en)

Answer (score 0):

[Cordless MediaBoard Pro](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/gaming/playstation_3/devices/3616&cl=US,EN) looks interesting to, it is designed for PS3, but apparently works fine with PC and after some key mapping with Mac